# How to change a value in a Reactive Array and rerun the helper

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, helper

I'm using the [Reactive Array](http://reactivearray.meteor.com/) package in Meteor and cannot figure out how to change a value in the array and have the helper rerun. This is such a basic thing, I must be missing something obvious but I've not been able to find an answer. Here's my code:

On the client:

```
test_arr = new ReactiveArray([3]);
```

Helper:

```
UI.registerHelper('array_test', function(){
  return test_arr.list();
});
```

In a template:

```
{{array_test}}
```

On screen I see '3' as expected, but if I change the value of the reactive array with this:

```
test_arr[0] = 4
```

nothing changes on screen, even though if I run test_arr.list() in the console, I see `[4]`. If I push a new value with:

```
test_arr.push(5)
```

then the helper reruns and I see `4,5` on the screen, correctly. So the value had been changed, but the helper did not rerun until I performed an unrelated 'push' operation.

I can't see anything in the docs about updating a value, only adding and removing values.

Is there any way to update a value in a reactive array, reactively?

Comment: Use splice. You can create a convenience method that deals with a single element.

Comment: Thank you. **test_array.splice(position, 1, new_value)** works perfectly. Even better, using **{{#each}}{{test_array}}{{/each}}** in my template, the helper only runs for the updated value, so it's efficient. Would you like to post your solution as an answer so I can accept it? I think it would be useful if this example was in the docs, because I can't be the only person to have missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ReactiveArray.splice()` to replace elements in a reactive array, or even create a convenience method that deals with a single element:

```
ReactiveArray.prototype.setAt = function(pos, item) {
  return this.splice(pos, 1, item);
};

arr = new ReactiveArray(['a', 'b', 'c']);
// ["a", "b", "c"]

arr[0];
// "a"

arr.setAt(0, "newVal");
// ["a"]

arr[0];
// "newVal"
```

Comment: I've also found that if rebuilding the array completely, it may be necessary to run **if (typeof my_array !== "undefined") m_array.clear();** in order to force a helper update.

Answer (score 0):

Look like this packages doesn't support reactive source when you set value in array by index. Try to check this one [package](https://github.com/jagi/meteor-reactive-array).